# How to use Critcl ByteArray?

Tags: tcl

I want to try out Critcl to enhance memory performance using a [Z-order curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) for a 2d-grid. What I need from Critcl is allocation, setter, getter and some size info. [Reading about the Critcl ByteArray](https://andreas-kupries.github.io/critcl/doc/files/critcl_cproc.html) and [examples](https://github.com/andreas-kupries/critcl/tree/master/examples) does not make me confident on how to do it.

How do I create and return a ByteArray (i.e. Z-order curve)?

Any caveats I should know about when using ByteArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should be using the `bytes` type instead (when you get a pointer to a structure that has a `len` field with the number of bytes in it, and an `s` field that is the pointer to the actual *read only* block of bytes. (As a `char *` and not an `unsigned char *` for reasons I don't know. And why it isn't `const` is another mystery to me; there are cases where that's indeed true, but you need to look at the `o` field to figure that out.)

To return a byte array, you use the `object` (or `object0`) result type, and make the object with, for example, `Tcl_NewByteArrayObj()`, or `Tcl_NewObj()` and `Tcl_SetByteArrayLength()`.

Here's an example (just the command definition) that does trivial byte reversing (since I don't understand Z-order curves at all):

```
critcl::cproc example {bytes dataPtr} object0 {
    Tcl_Obj *result = Tcl_NewObj();
    unsigned char *targetBytes = Tcl_SetByteArrayLength(result, dataPtr->len);

    for (int i = 0, j = dataPtr->len - 1; j >= 0; i++, j--) {
        targetBytes[i] = (unsigned byte) dataPtr->s[j];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Naturally, you'll want to read the [Critcl usage guide](https://andreas-kupries.github.io/critcl/doc/files/critcl_usingit.html) when getting this to work, and if you're going to produce errors (by returning `NULL`), remember to set an error message in the interpreter. You can get access to that by using `Tcl_Interp* interp` as your first pseudo-argument to the command you create with `critcl::cproc` (it's documented, but easily missed).

Comment: Which part is *read only*? `char const *`, `char const * const` or `char * const`? Z-order curves are 2d-arrays (or any-d for that matter) with a different adress calculation compared to the usual `arr[row][column]`. Setter would look like `arr[xy2addr(x,y)]=val`. If there is no way to set element without allocating new memory cache efficiency will be eaten alive by memory allocation overhead. Q: Can I set data in input bytes argument?

Comment: The `s` field of the structure that a `bytes` points to _should be_ `const unsigned char *` (I've filed a [bug report](https://github.com/andreas-kupries/critcl/issues/95) on that matter) because determining when it can be written to is tricky to the point where you would probably use a more basic `object` argument type at that point and not a `bytes`. Ask a separate question for the details there. The _always safe_ thing is to allocate a new result and work in that, as my example does.