# How to set data pointed to by argument using Critcl?

Tags: tcl

I would like to express something like this in [Critcl](https://andreas-kupries.github.io/critcl/doc/files/critcl_usingit.html):

```
void setter(int* grid, int value, int x, int y) {
  grid[xy2addr(x,y)] = value;
}
```

I'm in particular stuck on how to deal with `int* grid` in Critcl. `object`? `bytes`? Custom type maybe?

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814184).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case doesn't map very well onto Tcl's value model. The issue is that `grid` is (a pointer to) an updateable value collection. There are two ways of modelling this in Tcl in general:

1. As an opaque object.
2. As a variable containing a Tcl list (since in model terms, while Tcl values are thought of as immutable, Tcl *variables* are mutable).

I'll describe how to do both below, but I'm guessing that you're going to be thinking of these zOrder things as a distinct mutable type and that the additional modest one-time overhead of making the custom type will suit you far better.

### Opaque (Mutable) Objects

When working with opaque objects, you pass *handles* to them (basically just a name) around and then you unpack them as a [custom Critcl type](https://andreas-kupries.github.io/critcl/doc/files/critcl_cproc.html#section4). The trick is to create some helper functions in C to do the mapping (this can be in a `critcl::ccode` command) that does the mapping between names and pointers. This is slightly messy to do, but is just about building a couple of hash tables.

```
critcl::ccode {
    static Tcl_HashTable *zOrderMap = NULL, *zOrderRevMap = NULL;

    static Tcl_Obj *
    MakeZOrderObj(int *zOrder) {
        /* Initialize the two maps, if needed */
        if (zOrderMap == NULL) {
            zOrderMap = (Tcl_HashTable *) Tcl_Alloc(sizeof(Tcl_HashTable));
            Tcl_InitObjHashTable(zOrderMap);
            zOrderRevMap = (Tcl_HashTable *) Tcl_Alloc(sizeof(Tcl_HashTable));
            Tcl_InitHashTable(zOrderRevMap, TCL_ONE_WORD_KEYS);
        }
        int isNew;
        Tcl_HashEntry *hPtr = Tcl_FindHashEntry(zOrderRevMap, (char*) zOrder, &isNew);
        if (!isNew) {
            return Tcl_GetHashValue(hPtr);
        }
        /* make a handle! */
        Tcl_Obj *handle = Tcl_ObjPrintf("zOrder%ld", (long) zOrder);
        Tcl_SetHashValue(hPtr, handle);
        Tcl_IncrRefCount(handle);
        hPtr = Tcl_CreateHashEntry(zOrderMap, (char*) handle, &isNew);
        Tcl_SetHashValue(hPtr, zOrder);
        return handle;
    }

    static int
    GetZOrderFromObj(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *objPtr, int **zOrderPtr) {
        Tcl_HashTable *hPtr;
        if (!zOrderMap || (hPtr = Tcl_FindHashEntry(zOrderMap, (char *) objPtr)) == NULL) {
            Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_ObjPrintf("no such zOrder \"%s\"",
                    Tcl_GetString(objPtr)));
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
        *zOrderPtr = (int *) Tcl_GetHashValue(hPtr);
        return TCL_OK;
    }
}
```

With that helper code in place, you can then define a custom Critcl type like this:

```
critcl::argtype zOrder {
    if (GetZOrderFromObj(interp, @@, @A) != TCL_OK) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
} int*

critcl::resulttype zOrder {
    if (rv == NULL) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, MakeZOrderObj(rv));
    return TCL_OK;
} int*
```

That then lets you write your real code as something like this. Note that `grid` is defined as being of (custom) type `zOrder`, and that those can only be manufactured by some code that returns a `zOrder` as its result.

```
critcl::cproc setter {zOrder grid int value int x int y} void {
    grid[xy2addr(x,y)] = value;
}
```

(The deletion function that removes the entries from the hash tables and deletes the C array is left as an exercise.)

### Tcl List Variable

The other way of doing this is to make zOrder values be held in Tcl variables as lists of integers. This can be nice because it lets you look inside easily, but it can also be not so nice in other ways, as the code is not *constrained* to work with proper values and you expose your cprocs to more details of what's happening in Tcl.

```
critcl::cproc setter {Tcl_Interp* interp object varName int value int x int y} ok {
    /* Unpack the list of ints from the variable */
    Tcl_Obj *listObj = Tcl_ObjGetVar2(interp, varName, NULL, TCL_LEAVE_ERR_MSG);
    if (listObj == NULL)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    Tcl_Obj **listv; int listc;
    if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, listObj, &listc, &listv) != TCL_OK)
        return TCL_ERROR;
    int *grid = alloca(sizeof(int) * listc);
    for (int i=0; i<listc; i++)
        if (Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, listv[i], &grid[i]) != TCL_OK)
            return TCL_ERROR;

    /* The core of the functionality */
    grid[xy2addr(x,y)] = value;

    /* Repack the list of ints from the variable; this code could be optimized in this case! */
    for (int i=0; i<listc; i++)
        listv[i] = Tcl_NewIntObj(grid[i]);
    listObj = Tcl_NewListObj(listc, listv);
    Tcl_ObjSetVar2(interp, varName, NULL, listObj, 0);
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this has involved me writing quite a bit of code. Mapping mutability into Tcl isn't trivial at all.